# Meteor React Bootstrap Carousel: Failed to decode downloaded font & OTS parsing error

Tags: meteor, react-bootstrap

Getting the below error in Chrome and other browsers by trying to include a react-bootstrap carousel:

> Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
>   (index):1 OTS parsing error: invalid version tag
>   ...

[image: Print screen of the code]

Comment: It is better to paste the actual code into the question using the [edit] button and the "{}" feature rather than an image of the code.